# Azure Synapse VNet Integration with disabled "Managed Virtual Network"

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-synapse

I've an Azure Synapse created without the option "Enable Managed Virtual Network". I have to integrate Synapse in an Azure Virtual Network.
I'm following the documentation at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-connect-to-workspace-from-restricted-network).
What additional actions should I perform due to the missing configuration "Enable Managed Virtual Network"?

I would like to avoid to drop and recreate the Azure Synapse.

Answer (score 0):

Ah in your case if you want your notebook to access a linked storage resources under a certain storage account, add **managed private endpoints** under your Azure Synapse Analytics Studio. The storage account name should be the one your notebook needs to access.

And to add this **managed private endpoint** you would have to **enable a managed virtual network** for your workspace. Else you the service will be inaccessible as in snip below after I repro.

[image]

its only this step (Create private endpoints for workspace linked storage) that may require, Else you are good to follow the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-connect-to-workspace-from-restricted-network#step-5-create-private-endpoints-for-workspace-linked-storage) ahead .

Comment: So I can use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-connect-to-workspace-with-private-links) to connect to Synapse via private link and I don't need the managed virtual network settings )the image at step 2 has the "Managed Virtual Network" set to "No"). On the other side if I want that my Synapse can connect to VNet resources, I need the Managed Virtual Network set to true following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-connect-to-workspace-from-restricted-network). Is it correct?

Comment: edited confusion above, you can follow that doc, no need to create a managed Vnet if you don't want your notebook to access a linked storage resources under a other certain storage account 

Comment: which doc I have to follow?

Comment: this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-connect-to-workspace-from-restricted-network